# Fill NaNs in between two specific strings

Tags: python, pandas

I need to fill in the values in between two specific strings with some string value call it check. I looked into ffill() and interpolate(), however I did not see a way to do what I needed as ffill() would just bring the value down to the next value while I still want nans if the value is nan outside of rows that are start and finish.

| start_finish |
| --- |
| start |
| nan |
| nan |
| finish |
| nan |
| nan |
| start |
| nan |
| nan |
| start |
| nan |
| finish |

What the results should look like

| start_finish |
| --- |
| start |
| check |
| check |
| finish |
| nan |
| nan |
| start |
| nan |
| nan |
| start |
| check |
| finish |

Answer (score 2):

You can [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html)/[`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html) to build boolean masks for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# which cells are not NaN?
m = df['start_finish'].notna()

# NaNs cells after a start
m1 = df['start_finish'].eq('start').where(m).ffill()

# NaNs cells before a finish
m2 = df['start_finish'].eq('finish').where(m).bfill()

df.loc[m1 & m2, 'start_finish'] = 'check'
```

Output:

```
   start_finish
0         start
1         check
2         check
3        finish
4           NaN
5           NaN
6         start
7           NaN
8           NaN
9         start
10        check
11       finish
```

Intermediates:

```
   start_finish      m     m1     m2  m1 & m2
0         start   True   True  False    False
1           NaN  False   True   True     True
2           NaN  False   True   True     True
3        finish   True  False   True    False
4           NaN  False  False  False    False
5           NaN  False  False  False    False
6         start   True   True  False    False
7           NaN  False   True  False    False
8           NaN  False   True  False    False
9         start   True   True  False    False
10          NaN  False   True   True     True
11       finish   True  False   True    False
```